# Singleton by Jon Skeet clarification

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture, singleton

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested() {}
        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

I wish to implement [Jon Skeet's Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) in my current application in C#.

I have two doubts on the code

1. How is it possible to access the outer class inside nested class? I mean

   ```
   internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
   ```

   Is something called closure?
2. I am unable to understand this comment

   ```
   // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
   // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
   ```

   what does this comment suggest us?

Comment: haha I thought I had said that was a bit worried lol... turned out to be a different John Nolan

Comment: @thepirat000 - If he was only a participant on SO/Meta, I might disagree, but he does have enough influence in the actual world of programming that that might actually be legit - I'm sure someone has created it at one point or another.

Comment: This question's taxonomy is being discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316714/user-name-tag-in-question).

Answer (score 366):

1. No, this is nothing to do with closures. A nested class has access to its outer class's private members, including the private constructor here.
2. Read my [article on beforefieldinit](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx). You may or may not want the no-op static constructor - it depends on what laziness guarantees you need. You should be aware that .NET 4 [changes the *actual* type initialization semantics somewhat](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/) (still within the spec, but lazier than before).

Do you *really* need this pattern though? Are you sure you can't get away with:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }

    static Singleton() {}
    private Singleton() {}
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet - just to cofirm; R# is complaining about empty static ctor, so does it cause any issue if I move the initialization of the instance variable in the static ctor?

Comment: @Anindya: Nope, that's fine. You might want to mail JetBrains to complain though :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I just raised a concern to JetBrains about this (# RSRP-274373). Let's see what they can come up with. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet How can we use destrutor or dispose with the code

Comment: @Moons: You don't. A singleton lives for the duration of the AppDomain.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any reason not to use `Lazy<T>` so that you don't have to declare a static constructor for the magic `BeforeFieldInit` side-effect?

Comment: `FieldBeforeInit` is `MahaBharata` from `Microsoft`

Comment: @JonSkeet : I was curious about the Lazy<T> comment as well

Comment: @Michael: Nope, it's fine to use Lazy assuming you're on a platform supporting it. (I wrote the article long before Lazy cane along...) Be careful to specify the relevant option to guarantee single initialisation though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have through this link ,But i couldnot understand it what is the use of static Constructor :http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks I've just gone to have a play around and found the error "Access modifiers are not allowed on static constructors".

Comment: @harag: Well that's another reason why it wouldn't work, yes. But it's important that you understand the difference between static constructors (automatically called by the CLR when a type is used) and instance constructors (called by user code).

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you think about that memory barrier statement below? IIRC, locks do create an implicit memory barrier. And about the deadlock in singleton #6?

Comment: @ElMac: I'd have to look more carefully some time, taking a very long time to check. There are far more subtleties with memory barriers than many people realize, and I'm not an expert either. As for deadlocks - I don't know exactly what would be causing a deadlock here. I don't like singletons usually, but not because of deadlocks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, thank you. It's just out of curiosity. Concurrency in general is a complex topic, specially with Singletons.

Comment: looks like antipattern  ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/

Comment: @lazydeveloper: Which part is an antipattern? Personally I *usually* regard singletons as anti-patterns, but you linked to an article *recommending* the use of a singleton.

Comment: @JonSkeet i mean ,singleton fixed anti-pattern/improper instantiate issue.I am using it now.

Comment: @lazydeveloper: I still don't really understand what you're asking. Sometimes a singleton is reasonable, although personally I find it's *usually* a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet what's best idea for instanciate HttpClient objects. I am using singleton pattern. Is it good idea?

Comment: @lazydeveloper: It makes it harder to provide the client for test purposes, but it should work. We can't really say without more context, which is offtopic for this question. If you're still concerned, I would ask a new question, after checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 50):

Regarding question (1): The answer from Jon is correct, since he implicitly marks the class 'Nested' private by not making it public or internal :-). You might as well do it explicitly by adding 'private':

```
    private class Nested
```

Regarding question (2): basically what [the post about beforeinitfield](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) and [type initialization](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/) tell you is that if you have no static constructor, the runtime can initialize it at any time (but before you use it). If you do have a static constructor, your code in the static constructor might initialize the fields, which means that the runtime is only allowed to initialize the field when you ask for the type.

So if you don't want the runtime to initialize fields 'proactively' before you use them, add a static constructor.

Either way, if you're implementing singletons you either want it to initialize as lazy as possible and not when the runtime thinks it should initialize your variable -- or you probably just don't care. From your question I suppose you want them as late as possible.

That brings met to Jon's post about [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)'s, which is IMO the underlying topic of this question. Oh and the doubts :-)

I'd like to point out that his singleton #3, which he marked 'wrong', is actually correct (because lock's automatically [implies a memory barrier on exit](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx)). It also should be faster than singleton #2 when you use the instance more than once (which is more or less the point of a singleton :-) ). So, if you really need a lazy singleton implementation, I'd probably go for that one - for the simple reasons that (1) it's very clear for everyone that reads your code what is going on and (2) you know what will happen with exceptions.

In case you're wondering: I would never use singleton #6 because it can easily lead to deadlocks and unexpected behavior with exceptions. For details, see: [lazy's locking mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx), specifically ExecutionAndPublication.