# Two questions on Singleton C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

Consider the following code

```
 public sealed class Singleton
 {
     private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
     public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }

     static Singleton() {}
     private Singleton() {}
 }
```

**Question**

1) Here what is the purpose of static constructor ? (I know static constructor will be called before the first instance of the class is created).But in the context of above code
can't i use it without the static constructor?

2) I heard that one of the advantages of singleton is that it can be extended into factory.
   Since it is a sealed class ,how will you extend it into factory?can you give some example?

Answer (score 7):

The static constructor ensures that the singleton really isn't constructed before it's used. If the static constructor isn't present, the CLR has a lot more leeway about when it runs the type initializer. See my [article on beforefieldinit](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/beforefieldinit.html) and my blog post about [.NET 4 type initialization changes](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx) for more info.

As for turning a singleton into a factory - you'd really have to give more context. Your `Instance` property could *choose* whether to always return a reference to the same object or not, I suppose...

Comment: @Jon I think they actually got that code from one of your previous posts:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550925/singleton-by-jon-skeet-clarification/2550935#2550935

Answer (score 0):

1. <strike>There is no need for a static constructor.</strike> *SKEET!*
2. I've never heard of that.  You can't, obviously, if the class is sealed.  But you could moderately easily rewrite it as a factory, as there is only one way to instantiate it--through a property.  Change that into a method, and you have the starts of a factory.  The method may return the same instance each time, or may return an instance from a pool, or do whatever it wants.

I wouldn't suggest you have a factory property, as properties shouldn't be doing too much work.