# How to share an object among instances of a UserControl within one .NET WinForms application (not a static/shared field)?

Tags: winforms, object, share

When the 1st instance of our UserControl is initialized when a form with it is displayed, it should create an object with a boolean property which can be accessed by other instances of the UserControl which can be created in other forms of the same app.

This temporary shared object should work only within one application, another app will have another instance of this object.

An important requirement: it should not be a static (C#)/shared (VB.NET) field of the class.

And it would be nice if the shared object is destroyed automatically when the app is closed.

What is the best way to do that in .NET for WinForms applications?

Comment: Clearly the form is the best place to allocate it.  Have it pass that object to its user controls by assigning a property.  No point in worrying about destruction when your app closes, nothing survives anyway.  The form's Disposed event is otherwise a good one to know it is dead.

Comment: @Hans, what form properties do you mean? Can we create them on the fly, and they will not conflict with the existing infrastructure? Can you give some code samples, or at least, point ot the right form members?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a singleton.

Here is some examples of how to implement a singleton:
[Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

And here are a question which reference to that:
[Singleton by Jon Skeet clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550925/singleton-by-jon-skeet-clarification)

Comment: I do know about the singleton pattern but never thought it scould be used this way. Did you want to say that we need to add such a class to our assembly and then simply access the shared object from all instances of our user control using the syntax Singleton.Instance?

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly; yes, that would be one option.

Comment: yes, thank you for the idea! But if you reread the question carefully, there is one important requirement: we cannot use any static/shared member for some security reason. We need to create a dynamic storage at runtime - not an object or our usercontrol's member which can be found at design time. Something like SetProp/GetProp WinAPI functions which can be used to add unique window properties only the caller "knows" about.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought you meant you could not use a static field on your UserControl. You could use an object that you serialize to a file and deserialize for each UserControl, but I fail to see how that would be more secure.