# How to know file copy is in progress and how to know a particular Windows service is running?

Tags: c#, wcf, file-io, windows-services

In our application we are using windows service & WCF service. One of the task of the application is as follows:

1. Client copy file (large file) in specific server location using our admin web site.
2. We have a Windows service which pick up the file from server & dump data to database.
3. WCF service used those data to during service call.

We need solution for following situation

- If file copy is in progress windows service should not pick-up that file. **How to identify that?**
- If widows service is running and in that moment if any service request comes WCF service need to response that "**windows service is processing data so please make request again after sometimes**". **How to identify that the windows service is running?**

Comment: You want to inform the caller to a WCF service that is hosted in a Windows service that the Windows service is "running"?  Any response from the WCF service means the Windows service *is running*.  That seems really obvious, could you clarify that's actually what you're asking?

Comment: I have edited the question. Basically i want to know two things : 1. Is there any way know if file coping is in progress.? 2. Is there any way to know if a particular windows service do doing its processing?

Comment: It might be best to split this into two questions as they are unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If file copy is in progress windows service should not pick-up that file. 
How to identify that?
```

You can use .Net [FileWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class, a useful sample could be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv)

```
How to identify that the windows service is running
```

I think your windows service must be started when OS is starting,
If you want to know if file process is being done by the windows service, you can implement [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550925/singleton-by-jon-skeet-clarification/2550935#2550935)) or use Locking by [Mutex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Mutex_Process_Identifier.aspx) or [semaphore](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/inprocsemaphore.aspx).